# SSIS SQL statement error

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I created an SSIS package with source being a SQL query, destination being a flat file.

The SQL statement executes properly in SQL Server Management Studio, however it errors out when run from SSIS.

The statement is:

```
use Echo_active

select 
    DATEFROMPARTS(year(getdate()) - 1, month(getdate()) + 2, 1) as StartDate,
    eomonth(DATEFROMPARTS(year(getdate()) - 1, month(getdate()) + 4, 1) ) as EndDate,
    pd.[PA-PT-NO-WOSCD],
    pd.[PA-PT-NO-SCD],
    REPLACE(di.[PA-DX2-CODE],'.','') DiagCode,
    REPLACE(STR(di.[PA-DX2-PRIO-NO], 2, 0),' ', 0) DiagSeqNo, 
    di.[PA-DX2-PRESENT-ON-ADM-IND] POA,
    di.[PA-DX2-CODING-SYS-IND] DiagVersion
from 
    patientdemographics pd
left join 
    DiagnosisInformation di on pd.[PA-REGION-CD] = di.[PA-REGION-CD] 
                            and pd.[PA-HOSP-CD] = di.[PA-HOSP-CD] 
                            and pd.[PA-PT-NO-WOSCD] = di.[PA-PT-NO-WOSCD]
where 
    [pa-dsch-date] > = DATEFROMPARTS(year(getdate()) -1, month(getdate()) + 2, 1) 
    and [pa-dsch-date] <= eomonth(DATEFROMPARTS(year(getdate()) - 1, month(getdate()) + 4, 1))
    and di.[PA-DX2-PRESENT-ON-ADM-IND] <> ''
order by 
    di.[PA-DX2-CODE]
```

The error message I am receiving is :

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "
>       use Echo_active

```
select 
    DATEFROMPARTS(year(getda..." failed with the following error: "Cannot construct data type date, some of the arguments have values which are not valid.".
```

> Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

How could the same statement execute in one place but errors out in the other?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take out the USE. Your Connection Manager should be pointing at the correct catalog or you need to use a 3 part name

Comment: This is very likely is the result of SSIS having its own data types. Unfortunately, you cannot assume that a TSQL query will succeed in SSIS due to the data type difference. This is a "feature" that is challenging when moving data with SSIS.

Comment: @Tarzan Do you have an example of where you've encountered this? In my limited SSIS exposure, I've not encountered this

Comment: I appreciate your fast answer - any work around these types of problems ?

Comment: Data type problems are common for those of us who work with SSIS. Checkout (http://milambda.blogspot.com/2014/02/sql-server-integration-services-data.html) for a good explanation. To work around this you usually have to cast or convert the date. Here's another good blog (http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2012/05/10/datefromparts.aspx)

Comment: Once you've removed the USE statement, your query will work just as well from SSIS as it will from SSMS. I can run the StartDate/EndDate parts of your query just fine, evals to 2014-01-01 and 2014-06-30. My cursory search of the query's error `Cannot construct data type date, some of the arguments have values which are not valid` indicates this is generated from the Query Engine and is unrelated to any SSIS data type issues

Comment: @Tarzan Thank you for the links but I'm still a bit fuzzy. The first link explains some of the gotchas but the `date` based one only applies to an Execute SQL Task. JamieT's link just calls out that we now have an unambiguous mechanism for constructing date objects. I'm missing the issues with Data Flow Tasks. Any spare links to educate the masses? The differences in data types and range of values seems well identified. But I'm not sure of what search terms I'd used for find instances where a TSQL query works in SSMS but not in SSIS.

Comment: It looks like you are not mapping the result of the query to correctly. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280492.aspx